# The levels in kashrut

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, derabanan, bitul-batel-null

If a piece of a biblically forbidden food (such as a piece of pork), falls into a bowl of meat. We all know the rule, it's batul bshishim. How about a piece of food which is only rabbinically prohibited (a food that contains דברים מעמידים such as cheese). If the cheese would fall into a bowl of other cheeses, would the same laws of bitul apply regarding the shishim part. Or would we be even more meikel, because the food itself is only rabbinic?

Comment: Is the bowl hot? Is the rabbinic prohibition עיקרה מן התורה?

Comment: I don't understand your case. Is this Lach beLach on Min beMino or is it Yavesh beYavesh on Min besheEino Mino?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, batel b'shishim applies to both rabbinically and torah prohibited foods. It's basically the ratio at which chazal felt a tiny quantity of food became relevant.

However keep in mind it only applies to food when you can't separate the two foods. If a piece of non-kosher cheese fell into a bowl full of pieces of cheese, I see no reason why you wouldn't just pick it out.

Comment: If they are all the same color. Then you wouldn't be able to tell them apart

Comment: That would be an issue of Rov, not batel b'shishim.

Comment: Well if the issue is rov then the cheeses are forsure kosher because rov  of the cheese is kosher.

Comment: @Bachrach44 I'm really confused; I thought batel b'shishim generally only applies to bosor b'cholov (=kosher and kosher mixtures), not taruvos (=kosher and non-kosher)?

Comment: @SAH It applies to taaruvot. 60 is the quantification of how much taste spreads, so it is used whenever we have a case of ta'am k'ikar. (There are a few exceptions, I'm ignoring them for now). See Mishnah Chullin 7:4-5 and Yoreh Deah 98 (especially the rema in 98:1).