# If something is Kosher and has no alcohol in it, is it suitable for Muslims?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Muslims can eat anything that

- Has no alcohol in it
- Has no pork in it
- Has been slaughtered by A person who is Christian or Jewish or it's fish or it's not meat

My wife often brings home Kosher raw meat and chicken 
I had the other day some crisps which says Kosher on them even when they are bacon crisps , I assumed bacon her is just a flavour and that Jewish people don't eat pork 
Sometimes I eat crisps which says bacon on it but also says "suitable for vegetarians"

Is my wife doing wrong? Am I allowed to eat the crisps? (No alcohol in the ingredients)

Few more things to consider (my point of view as a Muslim) 
[Muslims aren't obliged to looked deep into things]

- I would eat something Halal (allowed for Muslims) that came slightly in contact with something not Halal
  Like if a drop of alcohol fell on a cucumber I am allowed to cut the part where the drop fell and eat the rest of the cucumber
- I don't have to check if the logo Kosher on a package is real proper Kosher that have been approved by a Rabbi. If a restaurant put the word Halal I am allowed to eat in there even if there are rumours that restaurant uses non-Halal meat, that's not my problem, the sins will be passed to him for tricking me

Comment: Is it possible? Yes -- there is a concept of nullification in certain extenuating situations. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38758/the-levels-in-kashrut http://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/611/when-its-null-and-void-understanding-batel-bshishim-one-sixtieth/

Comment: Wow Danno nice catch. Terve, do Muslim's accept any amount of nullification? If there is a one part per million of pork ( for argument's sake) would a Muslim be allowed to eat that?

Comment: @user6591 no, but we are not obliged to dig that deep, if a restaurant put a sign says Halal we can eat there even there are rumours about using non-Halal meat. So if something says Kosher we don't need to know if it has traces of non-Kosher, my question is way simpler, I'll wait for some less-technical/theoretical answers

Comment: Terve interesting. You might consider editing that info into your question in order to get a better answer. Most people here will not be expert in laws of Halal. For the record I often time see Muslim people buying meat products in Kosher groceries in my neighborhood and have always heard/assumed it was allowed.

Comment: @user6591 yes because we are allowed to eat any meat Christians or Jews slaughter except pork of course, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Please edit your post to incorporate all that's needed to understand your question, instead of leaving some of it in comments. Comments are ephemeral by design.

Comment: The "Kosher Bacon Crisps" are actually a tofu or grain products. Kosher “bacon” is made with a variety of non-pork ingredients; some types are vegetarian, while others use beef, lamb, duck, and sometimes turkey to recreate pork’s flavor.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing in the laws of kashrut that prohibits foods from containing alcohol. Alcoholic beverages are considered kosher (barring kosher issues aside from alcohol) and foods can be cooked with alcohol.

My understanding is that alcohol is not considered suitable for Muslims, so it would not be sufficient to confirm that the product is kosher. One would additionally at least have to confirm that it does not contain alcohol.

---

**Edit per revised question**

There are a variety of kosher products which have bacon flavoring. These products do not contain actual bacon and would satisfy the requirements you mentioned. It should be noted, though, that just because a product says "kosher" on it [does not mean that it is actually kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76156/1713) since the word "kosher" is not a trademarkable. You would want to verify that the product has the symbol of a reputable kosher certification agency. You can find a list of many of the most commonly seen reputable agencies [here](http://www.crcweb.org/agency_list.php).

You mentioned that you don't have to dig too deeply to determine if a product is ok, so it may be OK for your purposes (since you aren't concerned with whether the product is actually kosher; just whether it contains pork) if the company says it's kosher. Odds are if the company says it's kosher the product doesn't have any pork in it; however, you can only be sure that the production has been supervised and *certified* to not contain pork if it has a kosher certification on it.